# How to animate model for unity?

Tags: animation, export, transforms, unity

I have tried animate character from mixamo in blender. But the animation saved the transform location like 0, 0, 0 where I animate it. Everytime I call the animation in unity, the object moved to 0, 0, 0. I want the animation plays on local object. Idk where is my mistake.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is out of scope for Blender Stack Exchange. It should, instead, be asked in the appropriate Unity forum at <https://forum.unity3d.com/>.

Comment: I have asked in unity first, still no answer. It looks like I have to solve it by myself.